# jquery-bootgrid - changing default labels

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I am using jquery-bootgrid and want to know how to change the "loading" and "noResults" labels.

The doco http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation
states "All labels can be set and overridden on initialization respectively."

but I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just like that way:

```js
$(function()
{
  $("#grid").bootgrid({
    labels: {
      noResults: "where are my results"
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="grid" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
            <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.1.4/jquery.bootgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.1.4/jquery.bootgrid.min.js"></script>
```